# Select Item by property in list of complex object in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a complex object bound to an observable array via ajax call that looks something like below

```
----     ----          -----          ----
Id       Code          Type           Date
----     ----          -----          ----
1        pending       Application    10/29/2013
2        approved      lead           10/29/2013
3        received      Prospect       10/29/2013
```

Now in my view-model, I need to query this complex object kind of like SQL query i.e.

```
SELECT * from <object> where Id = 2
```

How can I do this client side? with knockout, or jQuery or some other library?

Comment: You iterate through the array's objects and find the results with JavaScript...

Comment: Do you have an object literal representation of the object rather than a table? And do you have an example of what you expect as the return value (e.g. an array or object literal, CSV string, array of values, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using [linqjs](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/). It will allow you to use familiar words like SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY, etc. In your case you can do something like the following:

```
var result = E.From(myObject).Where(function(x) {
    return x.id == 2;
}).ToArray();
```